# MATLAB - Assigning values within a for loop to an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

```
files_in_this_folder = dir('*.csv');
number_of_files = length(files_in_this_folder);
for index = 1:number_of_files;
    filename = files_in_this_folder(index).name; 

    A = readtable(filename);

    %convert data to matrix
    T = table2array(A);

    %cumulatively sum the daily energy consumption values
    y0 = T(:,3);
    y = cumsum(y0); 
    Etotal = max(y);
....
```

I have 25 files that this code is looping through, I need to store each 'ETotal' value to a 25x1 matrix. What do I have to do?

Comment: if my answer fixed your problem, do you mind accepting it. I will delete my comment after that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem, then here is a suggestion. Cannot you do something like the following:

```
Etotal = zeros(number_of_files, 1);    % This should go before the beginning of for-loop

Etotal(index, 1) =  max(y);    % Replace "Etotal = max(y)" with this line
```